# How to remove sitecore item field from indexing for coveo search

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, coveo

I want to know how to remove sitecore  item field from indexing for coveo search. I know it will possible trough coveo.searchprovider.config

https://developers.coveo.com/display/public/SitecoreV3/Customizing+the+Indexing+Parameters[enter link description here](https://developers.coveo.com/display/public/SitecoreV3/Customizing+the+Indexing+Parameters)

```
<exclude hint="list:AddExcludedField">
    <fieldId>{8CDC337E-A112-42FB-BBB4-4143751E123F}</fieldId>
</exclude>
```

But I want to be create property at field level which will indicate to exclude from index and using that property checkbox I want to exclude from coveo index.

Will it be poosible trough pipeline which explain following blog 
https://developers.coveo.com/display/public/SitecoreV3/Excluding+Sitecore+Items+From+Your+Index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, an inbound filter is what you are looking for.

```cs
public class ApplyCoveoInboundIndexShouldBeExcludedFieldFilter : AbstractCoveoInboundFilterProcessor
{
    public override void Process(CoveoInboundFilterPipelineArgs args)
    {
        if (args.IndexableToIndex != null && !args.IsExcluded && ShouldExecute(args)) {
            if (ItemShouldBeExcluded(args.IndexableToIndex.Item)) {
                args.IsExcluded = true;           
            }
        }
    }

    private bool ItemShouldBeExcluded(IItem item) {
        return item.GetFieldValue("SHOULD_INDEX_ITEM_FIELD_NAME") == "0";
    }
}
```

Modify the `ItemShouldBeExcluded` method according to your needs.